# Zsh - MacOS Catalina - automatically remove ansi codes into loop using ls command while keeping colors for a single command

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, ls

I have a tricky configuration about `ls` command. Indeed, I am using `grc` colorifying the results od different terminal commands using `iTerm2` into MacOS Catalina. My issue is about `ls`, I have for the moment into my `.zshrc` :

```
function ls { grc -es --colour=auto ls --color -Gh -C -rt "$@" ;}
```

and when I type `|~/Test_data| ls`, I get for example :

[image: results of ls command with grc]

But the issue occurs when I am using for example a loop command with `ls` :

```
|~/Test_data| for i in $(ls); do echo $i | xargs ls -lrt; done
```

Indeed, I get as results :

```
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[0m'$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;37mdata_0.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;37mdata_4.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;36mdata_3.py'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;37mdata_2.dat'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;35mdata_1.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;37mdata_1.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;36mdata_0.py'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;36mdata_4.py'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;37mdata_3.dat'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;35mdata_2.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;37mdata_2.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;36mdata_1.py'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;37mdata_0.dat'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;37mdata_4.dat'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;35mdata_3.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;37mdata_3.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[00;36mdata_2.py'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;37mdata_1.dat'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;35mdata_0.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[01;37m'$'\033''[m'$'\033''[01;35mdata_4.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
```

The results of `ls` command in `for i in $(ls)` loop generates ansi codes that cannot be processed by  pipe `xargs ls -lrt`.

A workaround is to write in this case :

```
|~/Test_data| for i in $(ls --color=never); do echo $i | xargs ls -lrt; done
```

and I get a "normal" list of files :

```
~/Test_data| for i in $(ls --color=never); do echo $i | xargs ls -lrt; done
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_0.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_3.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_2.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:34 data_1.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_0.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_4.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_3.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:34 data_2.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_1.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_0.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_4.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:34 data_3.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:32 data_1.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:34 data_0.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 fab staff 0 Apr 28 10:34 data_4.png
```

But I am bored to specify the option `--color=never` for `ls` at each time in my Shell scripts.

So I have found another alternative to remove these ansi codes by putting into my `~/.zshrc` :

```
function ls { grc -es --colour=auto ls --color -Gh -C -rt "$@" | gsed -r 's/'$(echo -e "\033")'\[[0-9]{1,2}(;([0-9]{1,2})?)?[mK]//g' ;}
```

This way, I have not to use `--color=never` **but Now, I loose colorified results of a simple `|~| ls` commmand.**

So, to summarize, I would like to keep, when I type the simple command `ls`, the colorifying of my first function (`function ls { grc -es --colour=auto ls --color -Gh -C -rt "$@" ;}`) while being able to use ls into `for i in $(ls ...); do ...; done` loop of Shell scripts without specifying at each time the option `--color=never`.

I don't know if it possible to switch between the 2 specifications. For example, maybe I could detect automatically if `ls` command is included in a `for loop` of shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
function ls { local color; [ -t 1 ] && color="--color"; grc -es --colour=auto ls $color -Gh -C -rt "$@" ;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, with your solution, colorifying is lost with a simple `ls` command ; you can see it here : https://i.imgur.com/Pvm9xbY.png

Comment: @youpilat13 It seems grc changed somehow the behaviour, I have updated the answer. Can you try ?

Comment: just a last request : could you explain please what `local color; [ -t 1 ] && color="--color";`does ?

Comment: It tests if standard output is a terminal, if yes then set the `--color`.